# Yii2 filters in gridview from array data

Tags: gridview, yii2

I'm stuck with next problem: I have some array with data. I wanna create datagrid with filters from it. I know that for ActiveRecord models attributes that you wanna filtering must be 'safe' in rules(). But how to be with information from array?

```php
$resultData = [
    '4' => [
        'id'          => 4,
        'key'         => 'dictionary_email',
        'value'       => 'Email',
        'description' => '//email comment'
    ],
    '5' => [
        'id'          => 5,
        'key'         => 'dictionary_username',
        'value'       => 'Name',
        'description' => '//name comment'
    ],
    '6' => [
        'id'          => 6,
        'key'         => 'dictionary_new-password',
        'value'       => 'New password',
        'description' => '//new password comment'
    ],
    '7' => [
        'id'          => 7,
        'key'         => 'dictionary_current-password',
        'value'       => 'Current password',
        'description' => '//current password'
    ],
];
```

I want to create GridView with filters from this data. My controller:

```php
$filtersForm = new FiltersForm;
if (isset($_GET['FiltersForm'])) {
    $filtersForm->filters = $_GET['FiltersForm'];
}
$resultData = $filtersForm->filter($resultData);

return $this->render('about', [
    'filtersForm' => $filtersForm,
    'resultData' => $resultData,
]);
```

my view:

```php
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $resultData,
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => ['id', 'key', 'value', 'description'],
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'  => $filtersForm,
    'layout'       => "{items}\n{pager}",
    'columns'      => [
        'id',
        'key',
        'value',
        'description',
    ],
]);
```

DataGrid is shown, but there is no filters.

Comment: See possible solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428492/using-yii2-with-array-of-data-and-a-gridview-with-sorting-and-filter

Answer (score 0):

For `ArrayDataProvider` you can specify filter for attribute the same way (by adding attribute to the `rules()` method of your model).

You can also set it manually and if it's `string` this declaration will have the higher priority:

```php
<?= GridView::widget([
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'description',
            'filter' => // ...
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what he wants. He is clearly not using ActiveDataProvider (which would be hooked to a model) but the ArrayDataProvider. I am struggeling with the same problem as my array (and the keys !) are dynamic. That means you can not use any rules. For yii-1 there was a solution, check this out:  http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/232/using-filters-with-cgridview-and-carraydataprovider/