# Using Yii2 with array of data and a Gridview with sorting and filter

Tags: arrays, sorting, gridview, filtering, yii2

I've an array

```
$resultData = [
    array("id"=>1,"name"=>"Cyrus","email"=>"risus@consequatdolorvitae.org"),
    array("id"=>2,"name"=>"Justin","email"=>"ac.facilisis.facilisis@at.ca"),
    array("id"=>3,"name"=>"Mason","email"=>"in.cursus.et@arcuacorci.ca"),
    array("id"=>4,"name"=>"Fulton","email"=>"a@faucibusorciluctus.edu"),
    array("id"=>5,"name"=>"Neville","email"=>"eleifend@consequatlectus.com"),
    array("id"=>6,"name"=>"Jasper","email"=>"lectus.justo@miAliquam.com"),
    array("id"=>7,"name"=>"Neville","email"=>"Morbi.non.sapien@dapibusquam.org"),
    array("id"=>8,"name"=>"Neville","email"=>"condimentum.eget@egestas.edu"),
    array("id"=>9,"name"=>"Ronan","email"=>"orci.adipiscing@interdumligulaeu.com"),
    array("id"=>10,"name"=>"Raphael","email"=>"nec.tempus@commodohendrerit.co.uk"),     
    ];
```

A dataprovider :

```
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'key'=>'id',
        'allModels' => $resultData,
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => ['id', 'name', 'email'],
        ],
]);
```

And the Gridview :

```
echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'id',

            [
            'attribute' => 'name', 
            'value' => 'name',
            ],
            [
            "attribute" => "email",
            'value' => 'email',
            ]

    ]
]);
```

As is, the code make me View the array in a grid, and the possibility to sort it when clicking on columns. That's ok.

But how to do to use filtering ?

I tried  with the following :

```
$searchModel = ['id' => null, 'name' => '', 'email' => ''];

echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,

        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'id',

            [
            'attribute' => 'name', 
            'value' => 'name',
            ],
            [
            "attribute" => "email",
            'filter' => '<input class="form-control" name="filteremail" value="da" type="text">',
            'value' => 'email',
            ]

    ]
]);
```

But it's not working. 
  Does I have to filter myself the object depending on the $get value ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? The search inputs are not shown?

Comment: What I mean by not working is that the input are show only if I put the filter like in the sample. 'filter' => '<input class="form-control" name="filteremail" value="da" type="text">',
            'value' => 'email',  But the data are not filtered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My solution with full code :

```
$resultData = [
    array("id"=>1,"name"=>"Cyrus","email"=>"risus@consequatdolorvitae.org"),
    array("id"=>2,"name"=>"Justin","email"=>"ac.facilisis.facilisis@at.ca"),
    array("id"=>3,"name"=>"Mason","email"=>"in.cursus.et@arcuacorci.ca"),
    array("id"=>4,"name"=>"Fulton","email"=>"a@faucibusorciluctus.edu"),
    array("id"=>5,"name"=>"Neville","email"=>"eleifend@consequatlectus.com"),
    array("id"=>6,"name"=>"Jasper","email"=>"lectus.justo@miAliquam.com"),
    array("id"=>7,"name"=>"Neville","email"=>"Morbi.non.sapien@dapibusquam.org"),
    array("id"=>8,"name"=>"Neville","email"=>"condimentum.eget@egestas.edu"),
    array("id"=>9,"name"=>"Ronan","email"=>"orci.adipiscing@interdumligulaeu.com"),
    array("id"=>10,"name"=>"Raphael","email"=>"nec.tempus@commodohendrerit.co.uk"),     
    ];

function filter($item) {
    $mailfilter = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('filteremail', '');
    if (strlen($mailfilter) > 0) {
        if (strpos($item['email'], $mailfilter) != false) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

$filteredresultData = array_filter($resultData, 'filter');


$mailfilter = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('filteremail', '');
$namefilter = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('filtername', '');

$searchModel = ['id' => null, 'name' => $namefilter, 'email' => $mailfilter];

$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
        'key'=>'id',
        'allModels' => $filteredresultData,
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => ['id', 'name', 'email'],
        ],
]);

echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,

        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'id',

            [
            'attribute' => 'name', 
            'value' => 'name',
            ],
            [
            "attribute" => "email",
            'filter' => '<input class="form-control" name="filteremail" value="'. $searchModel['email'] .'" type="text">',
            'value' => 'email',
            ]

    ]
]);
```

Comment: Just to be clear. 
Filters will not be shown if the filter is not instanceof Model

Comment: Use "not identical" (!==) instead of "non equal" (!=) in filter function, to avoid wrong filtering, see [stpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 2):

On the previous soultion. I created a loop to make the filters, columns and searchModel.

```
$items = [
    array("id" => 1, "name" => "Cyrus", "email" => "risus@consequatdolorvitae.org"),
    array("id" => 2, "name" => "Justin", "email" => "ac.facilisis.facilisis@at.ca"),
    array("id" => 3, "name" => "Mason", "email" => "in.cursus.et@arcuacorci.ca"),
    array("id" => 4, "name" => "Fulton", "email" => "a@faucibusorciluctus.edu"),
    array("id" => 5, "name" => "Neville", "email" => "eleifend@consequatlectus.com"),
    array("id" => 6, "name" => "Jasper", "email" => "lectus.justo@miAliquam.com"),
    array("id" => 7, "name" => "Neville", "email" => "Morbi.non.sapien@dapibusquam.org"),
    array("id" => 8, "name" => "Neville", "email" => "condimentum.eget@egestas.edu"),
    array("id" => 9, "name" => "Ronan", "email" => "orci.adipiscing@interdumligulaeu.com"),
    array("id" => 10, "name" => "Raphael", "email" => "nec.tempus@commodohendrerit.co.uk"),
];


$searchAttributes = ['id', 'name', 'email'];
$searchModel = [];
$searchColumns = [];

foreach ($searchAttributes as $searchAttribute) {
    $filterName = 'filter' . $searchAttribute;
    $filterValue = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam($filterName, '');
    $searchModel[$searchAttribute] = $filterValue;
    $searchColumns[] = [
        'attribute' => $searchAttribute,
        'filter' => '<input class="form-control" name="' . $filterName . '" value="' . $filterValue . '" type="text">',
        'value' => $searchAttribute,
    ];
    $items = array_filter($items, function($item) use (&$filterValue, &$searchAttribute) {
        return strlen($filterValue) > 0 ? stripos('/^' . strtolower($item[$searchAttribute]) . '/', strtolower($filterValue)) : true;
    });
}

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $items,
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => $searchAttributes,
        ],
            ]),
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => array_merge(
            $searchColumns, [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn']
            ]
    )
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

here are some improvements for the filtering function

```
function ($item) {
    $mailfilter = strtolower(Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('filteremail', ''));
    if (strlen($mailfilter) > 0) {
        return strpos(strtolower($item['email']), $mailfilter) !== false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

1. Use strtolower() in both places($item['email']) & mailfilter) function if you want your filter to be not case sensitive
2. Check also type for strpos() ("!== false" instead of "!= false") function, otherwise, it will not work while trying to filter for the first characters of the string

Answer (score 0):

A dataprovider :

```
if ($this->load($params)) {
    $name = strtolower(trim($this->name));
    $resultData= array_filter($resultData, function ($role) use ($name){
        return (empty($name) || strpos((strtolower(is_object($role) ? $role->name : $role['name'])),$name) !== false);
    });
}

$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'key'=>'id',
        'allModels' => $resultData,
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => ['id', 'name', 'email'],
        ],
]);
```

https://getyii.com/topic/736