# Yii2 GridView with ArrrayDataProvider search

Tags: php, yii2

I need help with search model for ArrayDataProvider. Let's say i have an array:

```
$cities = [
    ['city' => "Chicago", 'year' => 1984],
    ['city' => "Washington", 'year' => 2001],
    ['city' => Manchester", 'year' => 1997],
    //and so on...
];
```

I create an ArrayDataProvider:

```
$provider = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $catalog,
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => ['city', 'year'],
    ],
]);
```

Then I create a GridView:

```
echo \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $provider,
        'filterModel' => (new LibrarySearchModel()),
        'columns' => $columns,
        'showHeader' => true,
        'summary' => false,
    ]);
```

All works fine, but i need a filtering in GridView. There is no option to use ActiveDataProvider and I cant find any tutorial how to filter a data in ArrayDataProvider. 
Can someone help me with code for filter model or recomend the docs for my case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Yii2 with array of data and a Gridview with sorting and filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428492/using-yii2-with-array-of-data-and-a-gridview-with-sorting-and-filter)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is example of how to use [ArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#array-data-provider) with filters in the [GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#grid-view).

### Let's create simple action.

```
public function actionExample()
{
    $data = new \app\models\Data();
    $provider = $data->search(Yii::$app->request->get());

    return $this->render('example', [
        'provider' => $provider,
        'filter' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

This is classic Yii 2 approach to the GridView so I will not explain it (you can find details in the Guide linked above).

### Now the view.

```
<?php

echo \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $provider,
    'filterModel' => $filter,
    'columns' => [
        'name',
        'code',
    ],
]);
```

Again, nothing different from the ActiveDataProvider approach. As you can see here we are expecting two columns: `name` and `code` - these will be defined below.

### `Data` model.

Prepare the model that will handle the data source. Explanation is given in the comments.

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * Our data model extends yii\base\Model class so we can get easy to use and yet 
 * powerful Yii 2 validation mechanism.
 */
class Data extends Model
{
    /**
     * We plan to get two columns in our grid that can be filtered.
     * Add more if required. You don't have to add all of them.
     */
    public $name;
    public $code;

    /**
     * Here we can define validation rules for each filtered column.
     * See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html
     * for more information about validation.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'code'], 'string'],
            // our columns are just simple string, nothing fancy
        ];
    }

    /**
     * In this example we keep this special property to know if columns should be 
     * filtered or not. See search() method below.
     */
    private $_filtered = false;

    /**
     * This method returns ArrayDataProvider.
     * Filtered and sorted if required.
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        /**
         * $params is the array of GET parameters passed in the actionExample().
         * These are being loaded and validated.
         * If validation is successful _filtered property is set to true to prepare
         * data source. If not - data source is displayed without any filtering.
         */
        if ($this->load($params) && $this->validate()) {
            $this->_filtered = true;
        }

        return new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
            // ArrayDataProvider here takes the actual data source
            'allModels' => $this->getData(),
            'sort' => [
                // we want our columns to be sortable:
                'attributes' => ['name', 'code'],
            ],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Here we are preparing the data source and applying the filters
     * if _filtered property is set to true.
     */
    protected function getData()
    {
        $data = [
            ['name' => 'Paul', 'code' => 'abc'],
            ['name' => 'John', 'code' => 'ade'],
            ['name' => 'Rick', 'code' => 'dbn'],
        ];

        if ($this->_filtered) {
            $data = array_filter($data, function ($value) {
                $conditions = [true];
                if (!empty($this->name)) {
                    $conditions[] = strpos($value['name'], $this->name) !== false;
                }
                if (!empty($this->code)) {
                    $conditions[] = strpos($value['code'], $this->code) !== false;
                }
                return array_product($conditions);
            });
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

The filtering in this example is handled by the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function. Both columns are filtered "database LIKE"-style - if column value contains the searched string the `data` array row is not removed from the source.

To make it work like `and` conditions in ActiveDataProvider we put boolean result of every column check in the `$conditions` array and return product of that array in `array_filter`.

`array_product($conditions)` is equivalent of writing `$conditions[0] && $conditions[1] && $conditions[2] && ...`

This all results in the filterable and sortable GridView widget with two columns.

Comment: Thanks! Wery detailed and usefull!

Comment: foreach ($this->activeAttributes() as $attribute) {
    if (!empty($this->$attribute)) {
        $conditions[] = strpos(strtolower($value[$attribute]), strtolower($this->$attribute)) !== false;
    }
}