# Yii2 Gridview case insensitive sortable column

Tags: php, yii2

I use yii2 and I want to make gridview column 'description' sortable in a case insensitive way. There is my code:

```
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $query->find(),
    'sort' => [
    'attributes' => ['name','description],
    ],
    'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => $this->pageSize,
    ],
]);
```

When I click on column description to sort, it show like this:

- Job Title
- Doctor
- Teacher
- doctor
- teacher

As you see it sort case sensitive I want to sort case Insensitive, how I can do that? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In order **to sort rows of ArrayDataProvider in a case-insensitive way** you should extend ArrayDataProvider itself, because internally it uses ArrayHelper::multisort and if you want it sort the way you want you have to pass `SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE` as fourth argument to the method. By default its value equal to `SORT_REGULAR` constant.

Here the implementation:

```
<?php

namespace app\dataproviders;

use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

/**
 * Class ArrayDataProvider
 */
class ArrayDataProvider extends \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider
{

    /** @inheritdoc */
    protected function sortModels($models, $sort)
    {
        $orders = $sort->getOrders();
        if (!empty($orders)) {
            ArrayHelper::multisort(
                $models,
                array_keys($orders),
                array_values($orders),
                SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE
            );
        }

        return $models;
    }
}
```

And after it use the extended class instead of `\yii\data\ArrayDataProvider`

Example of usage:

```
$dataProvider = \app\dataproviders\ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $query->find(),
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => ['name','description'],
    ],
    'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => $this->pageSize,
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is quite good what Akmal wrote!

Maybe you need to specify  **key**  to the ArrayDataProvider, to get right id if your actionColumn not working well!

```
$dataProvider = \app\dataproviders\ArrayDataProvider([
   'allModels' => $query->find(),
   'key'=> 'id',
```

And if you want to filter your data within your gridview, you can use this solution:
[Yii2 GridView with ArrrayDataProvider search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073640/yii2-gridview-with-arrraydataprovider-search)
I tried this also and it works!!
(And the last tip: if you want to filter case intensive way, you can use stripos instead of strpos).
Good luck!