# How to render empty grid table in Yii?

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2, kartik-v

I am working on the Yii2 project. In this, on page load, I want to display an empty grid table. Data should get loaded to the Kartik GridView only after button click. I am able to display the grid view table with data on button click, but not able to display the empty grid table initially. 
To display data, I have added code as follows:

```
use kartik\grid\GridView;
<?=
        GridView::widget([
            'id' => 'crud-datatable',
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'pjax' => false,
            'floatHeader'=>true,
            'floatOverflowContainer'=>true,
        ])
        ?>
```

I was reading about **renderEmpty()** but don't know how to use this also I **tried sending NULL as a dataprovider** but was creating the issue. Is there any other GridView property that we can use to display an empty table initially?

Comment: One way to do that, not sure it is good for you or not. Before click you can pass ```$dataProvider`` array ```empty``` from the controller and after a click on button, you can pass an original array as you wish.

Comment: It shows error when you pass dataprovider as array, because gridview tries to count records from object. So niter array, empty object or '' works here for dataprovider

Comment: I mean to say you need to create custom $dataprovider with empty array.Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28452101/4781696

Comment: Thank you @HP371, This link solved the question

Comment: Glad to help you. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Yii2 with array of data and a Gridview with sorting and filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428492/using-yii2-with-array-of-data-and-a-gridview-with-sorting-and-filter)

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, as I don't have much knowledge of Yii, this link helped me partially. I will post my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, I have passed object of ArrayDataProvider as a value of dataProvider like,

```
$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider();
```